# The correct way to delete an Entity with a Many-to-Many Relationsship in EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have been struggling with deleting an entity with a Many-to-Many Relationship. I now have the following code which works, but my gut feeling tells me that I am going all wrong about it.

One of the strongest indicators for this for me is that the below code only works if I make AccountID and BrokerID Nullable in Relations.cs. If I do not make AccountID and BrokerID Nullable I only delete the 'Relations' entity and get an error when deleting the 'Accounts' entity.

Can someone tell me if I am on the right track or not? I think I should be able to delete an entity with a lot less effort than what I am doing right now while using EF6 more efficiently at the same time.

I am using Database First Approach in EF6.
Here is some code I am using.

Accounts.cs:

```
public partial class Accounts
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Accounts()
    {
        this.Relations = new HashSet<Relations>();
    }

    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Relations> Relations { get; set; }
}
```

Brokers.cs

```
public partial class Brokers
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Brokers()
    {
        this.Relations = new HashSet<Relations>();
    }

    public int BrokerID { get; set; }
    public string BrokerName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Relations> Relations { get; set; }
}
```

Relations.cs

```
public partial class Relations
{
    public int RelationID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AccountID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BrokerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RelationStartDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Accounts Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual Brokers Brokers { get; set; }
}
```

Deleting the entity..

```
using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
{
    var t = (from d in db .Relations
            where d.RelationID == relationID
            select d).Single();
    db.Relations.Remove(t);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
{
    var t = (from d in db.Accounts
            where d.AccountName == accountName
            select d).Single();
    db.Accounts.Remove(t);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That looks okay to me. I normally don't see the join table called out explicitly in code, but it looks like you want to track the start date of the relationship.

Comment: What bugs me is that I have to make AccountID and BrokerID both Nullable. Since they are in the relation they should never be null or there wouldn't be a relation in the first place. And I am also reading that I should be able to simply delete the Account entity with merely a reference to the Relation in order to delete it. Tried many different things to this regard, but did not get any of them working though.

Comment: You said you're using db first, so I take it this model is already baked? And you're just trying to use EF to deal with it in code? No wiggle-room for re-modeling it?

Comment: DB First indeed. But I can change the DB. So yes I can re-model I guess. What do you have in mind?

Comment: If you remove an `Account` you should also delete its `Relations`. Relations with a `null` `Account` don't make sense. You could use cascaded delete for that. Also, some advice, give `Relations` a more meaningful name, indicating that it's a junction class, e.g. `BrokerAccount`, and use singular names for classes and reference properties.

Comment: why are you selecting single from your relations table for delete?  You said its a many-to-many so there could be more than one row in the relations table for each Account.  You should be selecting all relations based on the Account ID and deleting them using the RemoveRange.  Then you can delete the parent Account row

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into cascading. Regarding the naming I agree and this is actually what I have here, but I wanted to simplify the name for publishing here to make it shorter. Not only made the name shorter, also left out some other fields of all entities. for the sake of simplicity. But thanks for pointing it out to me anyways.

Comment: @Kevbo. Yes, you are correct. It is just a piece of sample code I am using to train myself in EF6. In this case the deletion of a many to many relationship. In that context it is not so important that it is not practical to only have 1 account. But I will avoid this in the future as I see it raises questions and is only confusing people.

Comment: @JoeyJoystick one piece of advice since your just diving into EF6.  Most of the MS Doc refer to your db connection as a context.  Get used to that and start thinking of it as not being a database but rather an object store.   using (DbEntities context = new DbEntities()).  Also try not to create a context each time you want to use it.  There is overhead envolved so try to combine calls.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is the right way to address this, but why did I have answer yesterday and today this answer is gone? I don't mean a response like this, but an actual answer.